# Whitespace being added to bottom of body

Tags: html, css, whitespace

I've currently looked at every single post I can on Stackoverflow for a solution to this issue. I cannot figure it out. The website in question is http://ourcityourstory.com/. If you scroll to the bottom you'll notice about 23px of whitespace. This—to the best of my knowledge— wasn't there previously. It appears to have just shown up. Although, I could've missed it.

Anyways, I've done everything I can concerning margins, paddings, floats, overflow: hiddens, appending my "clearfix" class to elements. etc. I cannot figure out what is. Any help would be appreciated as this is truly boggling my brain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because of an `iframe` that is generated at the very end of the document.

That frame has no visible content (just some scripts) so you can set it's `position` to `absolute` to remove the space.

You can try making it with following CSS code:

```
$('iframe[class^=PIN]') { position: absolute; }
```

Comment: It's the pinterest related iframe.

Comment: Confirmed - I deleted the iFrame in Chrome Developer tools and the whitespace disappears.

Comment: Thank you so much. Since the iframe is dynamically generated via the Pinterest script I didn't even realize it was being inserted. Weird thing is that the pinterest button has been there for 8 months. We just now noticed the white space. No way we wouldn't have caught that before now. My guess is Pinterest changed something in their API. Either that or I'm insane. Thank you all. Now I just gotta figure out how to use JS to correctly target this iframe and add position: absolute to it.

Comment: I think it can be done using CSS only - I've added some code into my answer.